# Which number will replace the question mark in the following sequence of diagrams?

Tags: puzzle

[image]

As shown above, I need to guess what goes through the ?-part.
I tried number patterns, division, and all but I can't seem to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply left and right, and separately add top and bottom, you should see what's happening.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.